# What is a term for the evolution of idioms through error?

Tags: idioms, errors, language-evolution

At my place of work the idiom *bottom-up* (as in [bottom-up design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom%E2%80%93up_and_top%E2%80%93down_design)) is often used and debated as a way of doing things. However over the last year or so it's increasingly being expressed as *bottoms-up* design (as in the drinking idiom similar to *cheers*).

This is not by design, but rather in error as people hear the wrong idiom and repeat it, believing it to be correct usage.

It seems likely that in another year the correct idiom *bottom-up* may become the *minority* usage.

This corruption and replacement seems like a common feature of language evolution – is there a term for it (maybe *eggcorn*)?

Comment: Eggcorn, mondegreen, misheard lyric, malapropism. I wouldn't like to choose, nor do I know a definitive term.

Comment: This has happened to the term *head-up display* which has nearly disappeared, having been taken over by *heads-up display* for the same reason

Comment: The ["telephone game"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers)?

Comment: The end of your answer makes it clear that you are already familiar with the term *eggcorn*. For there to be a genuine question here, you need to explain why you are unsure that this is the right term.